# Class php is not find

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, localhost

I finished my website in localhost with MAMP and everything works fine.

But now I update it to my web site and I have this issue:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Model\FrontChapter' not found in /home/rafaueuu/public_html/pro4/App/Controller/FrontController.php:9
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0 [internal function]: App\Controller\FrontController->home()
>
> 1 /home/rafaueuu/public_html/pro4/App/Router/Route.php(38): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> 2 /home/rafaueuu/public_html/pro4/App/Router/Router.php(27): App\Router\Route->callAction()
>
> 3 /home/rafaueuu/public_html/pro4/index.php(51): App\Router\Router->match()
>
> 4 {main}thrown in /home/rafaueuu/public_html/pro4/App/Controller/FrontController.php on line 9

If I understud my controller don't find the Class but wy is working in localhost?

share you some code:

```
public function home(){
    $conn = new FrontChapter(); //LINE 9
    $lastChapter = $conn->lastChapter();
    require './view/frontend/home.php';
}



public function callAction(){
    if(is_string($this->action)){
        $elements = explode('@', $this->action);
        $class =  $elements[0];
        $method = $elements[1];
        $controller = "App\\Controller\\" . $class;
        $controller = new $controller;
        return call_user_func_array([$controller, $method], $this->matches);//LINE 38
    } else{
        return call_user_func_array($this->action, $this->matches);
    }
}

public function match(){
    if(!isset($this->routes[$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']])){
        header("location:/pro4/404");
    }
    foreach($this->routes[$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']] as $route){
        if($route->check($this->url)){
            return $route->callAction();//LINE 27
        } 
    }
    header("location:/pro4/404");
}
```

just ad my index in case:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
echo '<pre>';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo '<pre>';


$router = new App\Router\Router($_GET['url']);
//FRONTEND
$router->get('/', 'FrontController@home');
$router->get('/auteur', 'FrontController@author');
$router->get('/chapitre', 'FrontController@indexChapter');
$router->get('/contact', 'FrontController@contact');
$router->get('/chapitre- 
numero/:id','FrontController@displayChapter')->with('id', '[0-9]+');
$router->post('/chapitre-numero/:id_article' , 
'FrontController@comments')->with('id_article', '[0-9]+');
$router->get('/signaler/:id' , 'FrontController@reportComment')- 
>with('id', '[0-9]+');
$router->get('/404' , 'FrontController@erreur404');
$router->get('/404-article' , 'FrontController@article404');

//BACKEND
//gestion chapitres
$router->get('/chapitres-admin', 'BackController@displayChapter');
$router->post('/modifier-chapitre/:id', 
'BackController@updateChapter')->with('id', '[0-9]+');
$router->get('/modifier-chapitre/:id', 
'BackController@updateChapter')->with('id', '[0-9]+');
$router->get('/effacer-chapitre/:id', 
'BackController@deleteChapter')->with('id', '[0-9]+');
//nouveau chapitres
$router->get('/nouveau-chapitre', 'BackController@createChapter');
$router->post('/nouveau-chapitre', 'BackController@createChapter');
//gestion commentaires
$router->get('/commentaires-admin', 
'BackController@displayComments');
$router->get('/valider-com/:id', 'BackController@validateComment')- 
>with('id', '[0-9]+');
$router->get('/supprimer-com/:id', 'BackController@deleteComments')- 
>with('id', '[0-9]+');
//gestion des administrateurs
$router->get('/nouveau-admin', 'BackController@createAdmin');
$router->post('/nouveau-admin', 'BackController@createAdmin');
$router->get('/modifier-admin/:id' , 'BackController@updateAdmin')- 
>with('id', '[0-9]+');
$router->post('/modifier-admin/:id' , 'BackController@updateAdmin')- 
>with('id', '[0-9]+');
$router->get('/effacer-admin/:id' , 'BackController@deleteAdmin')- 
>with('id', '[0-9]+');
$router->get('/gestion-admin' , 'BackController@displayAdmin');
//message
$router->get('/message-admin' , 'BackController@displayMessage');
$router->post('/contact' , 'BackController@postMessage');
$router->get('/effacer-message/:id' , 
'BackController@deleteMessage')->with('id', '[0-9]+');
//connexion
$router->get('/connexion', 'BackController@login');
$router->post('/connexion', 'BackController@login');
$router->get('/deconnexion' , 'BackController@logout');
$router->get('/admin', 'BackController@indexAdmin');

$router->match();
```

the composer.json

```
{
"require": {},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\" : "App",
        "Model\\" : "Model"
    }
}
}
```

I hope some one understand me i just started php, thx for your help

EDIT: i use only namespaces not include function maybe is something about composer auto load?

Comment: So, do you have class `FrontChapter` in `App\Model` namespace?

Comment: @freeek yes in the namespace App\Model

Comment: We need to check `composer.json` autoload section and this class structure then. Where do you keep it, can you create this class it from any other file?

Comment: @freeek Just edit the question now

Comment: Check folder name, and also, this could be crazy - try add slash after: `Model/`.

Comment: The file name is rigth and no changes with Model/

Answer (score 1):

Here are two things to try in case you haven't already:

1. Run `composer install` on the server.
2. Change this `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` to this `require '/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: I try the second option and i have a new problem vendor is not find. And for the first i nedd to install composer on my web server ?

Answer (score 1):

when you use the namespace or use it, the class path doesn't start with the slash '\'.
but when you have to recall a class and use it directly, you have two possibilities:

use App\Model\MyClass

$obj = new MyClass;

or

$obj = new \App\Model\MyClass;

because depending on the use you make of it, the paths are different.
happy Holidays

Comment: happy holidays to you to. I think i understand that, my problem here is that my code works fine in my local server but have this problem on the web server?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very simple and if you are a noob like me and have the same problem dont forget to do a `composer dump-autoload -o` in your console to generate the autoload files for news namespaces.